# Model complete theories have AE axiomatization

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

I would like to show that every model complete theory $T$ has an AE axiomatization. The problem comes up as Exercise 2.5.15 in Marker's book, but I'm really not sure how to get started with it

Answer (score 4):

Exercise 2.5.15 in Marker actually says something different: if T is any theory with the property that the union of any chain of models of T is a model of T, then T has AE axiomatization. (There are hints in the exercise as to how to prove this.) This proves your question, though, because if T is model complete, then any chain is an elementary chain, so the union of a chain of models of T will be a model of T.